# DHCPREQUEST not reaching interface wlan0

Tags: linux, dhcp

I have lots of DHCP requests on my Raspberry Pi Zero that never reaches the netowrk interface. All these entries in /var/log/syslog does not reach my "tcpdump -i wlan0 port 67 or port 68". Seems they are logged but never sent. I do get a few DHCP requests on the network, The normal discover, the renew after 1 hour, and the rebind every 1h45m (the they run in parallel I do not understand).

Any good explanation ?

I am using Raspbian, Jesse, fully patched (needed gadget mode and had issues with newer releases).

My pi has issues with losing network, and ifdown/up did not fix it. I suspected the 2 hour lease time was a factor - Linux releasing the IP because it does not understand the ACK. Now my check script does a shutdown -r if I fail to ping google, and I do net have any IP address assigned to wlan0 in 2 attempts 5 minutes apart. Since then it works relative stable, with an occasional reboot. It is running on NAT'ed WiFi and creating an OpenVPN tunnel for me to access it from a VPS, both ssh and reverse proxy for its web server.

```
Feb 26 06:31:12 raspberrypi dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on wlan0 to 192.0.2.1 port 67
Feb 26 06:31:27 raspberrypi dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on wlan0 to 192.0.2.1 port 67
Feb 26 06:31:36 raspberrypi dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on wlan0 to 192.0.2.1 port 67
Feb 26 06:31:47 raspberrypi dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on wlan0 to 192.0.2.1 port 67
Feb 26 06:31:58 raspberrypi dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on wlan0 to 192.0.2.1 port 67
```

Comment: Most of us use Raspbian Stretch by now for good reasons. One reason is that it has newer bug fixed wifi driver. Seems not to be a simple setup with NAT, OpenVPN and so on. Try to set the interface to promiscuous mode. I had seen curious behavior with **arp** requests together with DHCP, mostly with virtual interfaces.

Comment: Have you checked the WiFi is associated with the AP? Use a `wpa_cli status` command to check that.